# How to convert String to Function in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

```
fun getApple(): Apple = {...}

fun setOrange(orange: Orange) {...}

val funMap = hashMapOf("getApple" to this::getApple, "setOrange" to this::setOrange)

funMap["getApple"]()
```

I want to put the method on the map. 
Then get the method by string, but can't be invoked if function type different. Any other way to convert the string to function?

---- update ----

I used to use the java reflection before, I am looking for a more efficient way

Answer (score 2):

It's possible, but your map has type `Map<String, KFunction<Any>>`. For `KFunction` you have method `.call` and `.callBy(Map<KParameter, Any>)`. So, see this example (I've also added logging when function invoked):

```
class StackStringFunction {

    data class Apple(val size: Int = 1)
    data class Orange(val color: String = "orange")

    fun getApple(): Apple {
        println("Calling getApple()")
        return Apple()
    }

    fun setOrange(orange: Orange) {
        println("Calling setOrange(Orange) with param $orange")
    }

    val funMap = hashMapOf("getApple" to this::getApple, "setOrange" to this::setOrange)
}

// Invocation example:
with(StackStringFunction()) {
    this.funMap["getApple"]?.call()
    this.funMap["getApple"]?.callBy(mapOf())

    this.funMap["setOrange"]?.call(StackStringFunction.Orange())
    this.funMap["setOrange"]?.callBy(mapOf(this.funMap["setOrange"]!!.parameters[0]to StackStringFunction.Orange()))
}
```

And the output:

```
Calling getApple()
Calling getApple()
Calling setOrange(Orange) with param Orange(color=orange)
Calling setOrange(Orange) with param Orange(color=orange)
```

As you see, via `::sth` you obtain not a lambda, but `KFunction`, and using KFunction interface you are able to call those methods.

Comment: Thanks.This requires reflection, I used to use the java reflection before, I am looking for a more efficient way.Thank you for your help

Comment: I thought about casting it to most generic type, like `(vararg args: Any?) -> Any?`, but I see there is no vararg lambdas in kotlin :(